# Argument labels '(fileNamed:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to transition scenes from MenuScene to GameScene. I am getting stuck here. I have the GameScene class completed so I am not sure why this error is here.

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if atPoint(location).name == "Play" {
                let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameSene") //error
                scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                self.view?.presentScene(gameplay!, transition: SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 1))

            }

            if atPoint(location).name == "Highscore" {
                scoreLabel.removeFromParent()
                createLabel()

            }}
```

Comment: Type `GameScene(` and look what Xcode suggests.

Comment: What is the error you get? Also, are you able to share your `GameScene` code with us?

Comment: Probably let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameSene") has a typo in it, I'm sure it is probably supposed to be GameScene
or you haven't created a GameScene.sks file?

Comment: We need to see your definition of GameScene, the error is likely to be there.

Comment: Clean the project then quit and restart Xcode perhaps?

Comment: check out my answer below, it should fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I can recreate this error to the tee, when my Scene that I am trying to transition to has a corresponding SKS file, and I have an

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
```

and a

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

change the init to

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView)
```

remove

```
super.init
```

and all should work as planned